# cannot reuse local value in an eks module in aws

Tags: terraform

I have different IAM ARN users and I cannot find an easy way to reuse the `locals users` list that defines the users to add in `kms_key_administrators` and also in `aws_auth_users`. The `aws_auth_users` requires the ARN IAM and also the username but the `kms_key_administrators` requeres the full list of users.

Any idea on how can I reuse the locals here?

Here is the EKS block module that I'm using in the `main.tf` file.

```
locals {
   users = tolist(["arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1", "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2", "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3"])
}

# Module EKS
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 19.0"

  cluster_name    = "eks"
  cluster_version = "1.24"

  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true
  vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets
  kms_key_administrators = local.myusers
  enable_irsa = true
  create_kms_key = true
  create_cluster_security_group = false
  cluster_security_group_id = aws_security_group.mysg.id

  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    disk_size = 100
  }
  create_aws_auth_configmap = false
  manage_aws_auth_configmap = true

  aws_auth_users = [
    {
      userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1"
      username = "user1"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    },
    {
      userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2"
      username = "user2"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    },
    {
      userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3"
      username = "user3"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    }
 ]

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    general = {
      desired_size = 4
      min_size     = 2
      max_size     = 6

      labels = {
        env = "test"
      }

      instance_types = ["t3.small"]
      capacity_type  = "ON_DEMAND"
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: Do all the users have the `/user/env/<env name>/username` or not?

Comment: The users have different paths @MarkoE

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, but the two I can think of are to either use the actual data structure you actually need, like this:

```
locals {
  users = {
    user1 = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1"
    user2 = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2"
    user3 = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3",
  }
}
```

Or you can build it from your list, which doesn't need the `tolist` function call.

```
locals {
  users = [
    "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1",
    "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2",
    "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3",
  ]

  constructed = { for user in local.users : reverse(split("/", user))[0] => user }
}

output "constructed" {
  value = local.constructed
}
```

That uses the [reverse](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/reverse) and [split](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/split) methods in a [for expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) to yield the same result.

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + constructed = {
      + user1 = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1"
      + user2 = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2"
      + user3 = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3"
    }
```

---

In both these cases, you could use the data the same. For example:

```
locals {
  arns = [
    "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1",
    "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2",
    "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3",
  ]

  users = { for arn in local.arns : reverse(split("/", arn))[0] => arn }
}

output "kms_key_administrators" {
  value = local.arns
  # or
  # value = values(local.users)
}

output "aws_auth_users" {
  value = [for user, arn in local.users : {
    userarn  = arn
    username = user
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which yields outputs:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + aws_auth_users         = [
      + {
          + groups   = [
              + "system:masters",
            ]
          + userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1"
          + username = "user1"
        },
      + {
          + groups   = [
              + "system:masters",
            ]
          + userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2"
          + username = "user2"
        },
      + {
          + groups   = [
              + "system:masters",
            ]
          + userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3"
          + username = "user3"
        },
    ]
  + kms_key_administrators = [
      + "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1",
      + "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2",
      + "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3",
    ]
```

Note, that outputs are just used for illustrative purposes.

---

Lastly, if you need the user values to include the full path, you can just change the construction to split on `user/`, and you'd be set.

```
  users = { for arn in local.arns : reverse(split("user/", arn))[0] => arn }
```

Yielding the new output:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + aws_auth_users         = [
      + {
          + groups   = [
              + "system:masters",
            ]
          + userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1"
          + username = "env/test/user1"
        },
      + {
          + groups   = [
              + "system:masters",
            ]
          + userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2"
          + username = "env/test/user2"
        },
      + {
          + groups   = [
              + "system:masters",
            ]
          + userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3"
          + username = "user3"
        },
    ]
  + kms_key_administrators = [
      + "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user1",
      + "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/env/test/user2",
      + "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/user3",
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I came up with is the following:

```
locals {
  users = ["env/test/user1", "env/test/user2", "user3"]
  aws_auth_users = [for user in local.users : {
    userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/${user}"
    username = user
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
   }
  ]
  kms_key_administrators = [for user in local.users : "arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/${user}"]
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 19.0"

  cluster_name    = "eks"
  cluster_version = "1.24"

  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true
  vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets
  kms_key_administrators = local.kms_key_administrators
  enable_irsa = true
  create_kms_key = true
  create_cluster_security_group = false
  cluster_security_group_id = aws_security_group.mysg.id

  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    disk_size = 100
  }
  create_aws_auth_configmap = false
  manage_aws_auth_configmap = true

  aws_auth_users = local.aws_auth_users

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    general = {
      desired_size = 4
      min_size     = 2
      max_size     = 6

      labels = {
        env = "test"
      }

      instance_types = ["t3.small"]
      capacity_type  = "ON_DEMAND"
    }
  }
```